# How to install prettytable in colab

Tags: python, prettytable

I could not find other questions on that, if it is repeated just let me know please.

I want to use prettytable on a colab notebook, but I don't know how to install it. Can anyone give the command line for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you just have to call:

```
!pip -vvv install prettytable
```

Works like magic!